# How to change DateFormat like this? on Android

Tags: android, date

This is UTC time from `django` rest `api`.

**For example**

```
2016-09-26T02:58:26.154543Z

2016-09-25T08:40:41.891129Z

2016-09-24T13:25:16.397189Z
```

It comes as `"created_date": "2016-09-24T13:25:16.397189Z"`,

And I want use it for this code

```
    public String beforeTime(Date date){

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long dateM = date.getTime();

        long gap = now - dateM;

        String ret = "";

//        sec     min hour
//        1000    60  60
        gap = (long)(gap/1000);
        long hour = gap/3600;
        gap = gap%3600;
        long min = gap/60;
        long sec = gap%60;

        if(hour > 24){
            ret = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
        }
        else if(hour > 0){
            ret = hour+"hours ago";
        }
        else if(min > 0){
            ret = min+"mins ago";
        }
        else if(sec > 0){
            ret = sec+"secs ago";
        }
        else{
            ret = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
        }
        return ret;

    }
```

so I made a code, and it's for parameter of `beforeTime`

```
 String stringDate = "2016-09-26T03:02:37.477821Z"; #this is example
 java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.~~"); # i don't know this part
 java.util.Date dateToUse = format.parse(stringDate);
```

**Question :** Please how to i set that format? "yyyy.MM.dd~~ " this, help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");`

`S` is milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Try below code it will give you what you need...

```
try {
                        String stringDate = "2016-09-26T03:02:37.477821Z";
                        try {
                            Date simple_edate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
                                    Locale.ENGLISH).parse(stringDate);
                            SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd",
                                    Locale.ENGLISH);
                            String newdate = newFormat.format(simple_edate);
                            Log.e("date", "= "+ newdate.toString());

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("error", e.toString());
                        }

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Let me know once it works for you.

Comment: Thankyou Preetika Kaur, it works but i modified it as i need thanks